# Vim search and move the searched string

Tags: vim

There is a similar question on moving the searched string to the end of the file or to the beginning of file

```
:g /<pattern>/m0 -> beginning of the file.
:g /<pattern>/m$ -> beginning of the file.
```

Is there way to search and move to the beginning of a line. Any tutorial link to learn this ?

Thank you

Comment: Please give an example of the "before" and "after" versions of the text that you have in mind.

Comment: your example with `:g` doesn't move "searched string", it moves the line containing the matched string. completely different things. like @benjifisher said, please give examples of single match in a line, multi-matches in a line, no matches in a line, what result you want to get. I feel the solution would be easy. but should know your requirement first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do movement inside the current line with `:substitute` alone, no need for `:g`. You need to augment the `<pattern>` so that the text before / after is also captured (in `\(...\)` groups). This lets you "rearrange" the matches in the replacement part.

Move (first, for last use `.*` instead of `.\{-}`) match to beginning:

```
:%s/^\(.\{-}\)\(<pattern>\)/\2\1/
```

Move to end:

```
:%s/\(<pattern>\)\(.*\)$/\2\1/
```

Comment: One of my colleague gave almost a similar script above.Divide the line into three captures and rearrange them. :%s/^\(.*\).string.\(.*\)$/string\1\2/g

Comment: Thanks! That solution captures one too much, and you're repeating the string; but it's working, too!

Comment: :%s/^(.*)<identifier_to_start_capture>(.*)<identifier_to_stop_capture>(.*)$/\2\1\3/g

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `:g` command allows you to put any Ex command where your examples have `m0` and `m$`.  The `:move` command (short form `:m`) can take any number as an argument, and there are other possibilities.

If you want to move a line after Line 17, then use `:m17`.  If you want to move it before Line 17, then use `:m16` or `:m17-` (short for `:m17-1`).  I often find it useful to mark a line (`ma` in Normal mode or `:mark a`) and then

```
:g/<pattern>/m'a-
```

```
:help :global
:help :move
:help {address}
```